# Can an android app be installed/converted to run on an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, android

I have an android project that targets Android 2.2 (developing in Eclipse).  Exporting the android project to the Droid Incredible works perfectly.  Is it possible to export the project to a file suitable for installing on an iphone?  I know that most iPhone apps are developed using xCode, but I'm not sure if xCode packages into a .apk or other file format that's equivalent.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Considering iOS is based on ObjectiveC and Android OS is based on Dalvik VM I don't think this will be a very easy process.  In fact, it will most likely require a complete rewrite for the different platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Only if you write or port your own complete Dalvik VM (in Objective C or Javascript), plus developing the runtime support needed for any and all API calls that your app uses, and bundling all that with your app, as that would be the only way to run a regular Android project on an iPhone.

A non-trivial amount of work.

Completely rewriting the app in Objective C and Cocoa Touch would be magnitudes easier.

Comment: I see.  I figured they probably weren't compatible.  Bummer.  Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Not even remotely possible. Android and iOS are completely different environments. There are a few frameworks for developing applications that'll run on either, but the results often end up looking kind of weird on both platforms.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot export an Android application and run it in an iPhone because the hardware/software stacks/APIs/etc. are different.

However, if you build an application using for instance [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/) (a HTML5 based application framework), it is possible to deploy it on different mobile platforms.

If you feel curious about multi-platform mobile frameworks (Android/iPhone) you may find this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30953/is-there-a-multiplatform-framework-for-developing-iphone-android-applications) interesting.